# Tag badge glitch

Tags: feature-request, bug, tag-management, badge-tracking, score

How is this possible?

[image]

[image]

What I mean here is there's a bug, as the number of answers and the score shown on my reputation chart is different than of the number shown in "Select your next badge". I am talking about the elementary-number-theory tag, which I have the highest score and the second most answers.

I hope the moderators will fix it soon.

Comment: It seems that something similar was mentioned here: [“Next tag badge” panel score and answers counter discrepancy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/267818) I am not sure from what I read in the answers whether the problem mentioned there was fixed, but the workaround mentioned in the answer might be worth trying (=change the badge chosen to be tracked and then change it back).

Comment: Yeah, that works too.